# Is my logic textbook incorrect?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I am reading "Mathematical Methods in Linguistics," corrected first edition, by Barbara H. Partee, Alice ter Meulen, and Robert E. Wall. The textbook is brilliant, though I believe there is an error in it. Given:

$$A = \{b,c\} \text{ and } B = \{2,3\},$$

the textbook holds the following to be true (Chapter two, question 2a) :

$$(A \times B) ∪ (B \times A) = \emptyset.$$

I can see this being the case for an intersect, though not for a union.

Comment: Probably should be intersection as you suggest.  If this is question 2a, try having a look through 2b, 2c,...  If they make sense with the union being replaced by intersection, then I think you can be pretty confident that it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong indeed, probably meant to be an intersection as you say.